# Can't restore lost windows partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, lvm, testdisk

I was trying to install Ubuntu budgie, I clicked on erase disk and setup lvm,  but I  didn't click ok when the confirmation window poped up, I quit the installation. Tried booting back into windows but my screen remained blank so I inserted my live usd again and opened testdisk from there. 
Realized my partitions had been deleted and replaced with the lvm partition.

And can't recover with testdisk too, any help will really be appreciated.. 
I'm loosing my mind

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use a data recovery software. You'll need to install a new copy of Windows to **another** hard drive (because you could overwrite your lost data). I recommend to buy a new internal hard drive. If you're on a laptop, buy a 2.5" HDD (of course, you can buy an SSD too, but make sure the capacity is more than 30GB). This will only help if your laptop has a SATA slot. Remove the back cover of your laptop and you should see it there. If you have an SSD, there's a chance you have M.2 slot without SATA slot, but I hope that's not your case.

So, buy a 2.5 inch HDD or SSD and replace your current drive with it. Then, buy a 2.5 inch hard drive enclosure with a USB cable. Install Windows on the new hard drive and then plug in the enclosure USB cable.

Install a data recovery software. Yeah, they are not free but you should pay for it if you want your data back. Also, tell me if you found a free data recovery software ;).
I recommend MiniTool data recovery.

After you've installed the data recovery software, go to computer management and format your external hard drive (MAKE SURE TO USE QUICK FORMAT). Then, create an NTFS partition inside the hard drive.

Select the NTFS partition in the data recovery software and wait until it recovers your data.